# Why do JavaScript filenames sometimes have dots?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, path, operating-system

I have the following question and is it because there are javascript file names with dots?

For example:

In a node js project with express, I found the following files:

user.route.js

user.controller.js

Comment: What's the problem with the dot in your mind? I'm not sure why that would be surprising. Many files have extra dots. For example, when browsers download stuff, sometimes they use `foo.docx.part` and strip the `.part` when the DL is complete. Or `foo.tar.gz`...

Answer (score 1):

Because it very clearly when you read the filename, you can know the responsibility of file, object is handling, Business model of project.
Easy maintain, fix bug.

Answer (score 0):

It is the same reason why you put files in different directories. Why would we do that? We want to organize the files in a manageable manner. So, we put routing related files in `routes` directory, business logic related files in `service` directory.

Another way of organizing files is to have the type of the file mentioned in the name itself. The file name `user.route.js` says, it contains `routes` related to `user`. The file `user.controller.js` says, it contains `controller` functions related to `user`.

If you think more about it, it is similar to having extensions in file names. Files ends with `.js` tells us, it is a `JavaScript` file. Same goes for `.css`, `.html`, etc files. The same way, files ends with `.route.js` tells us, it is a file that has routing related JavaScript code. So, what does files that ends with `.controller.js` tells you?